# Не срабатывает JavaScript при переходе по ссылке в WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

Есть WebView с JavaSript'ом, в результате которого некоторые элементы интеренет-страницы скрываются. К примеру, заголовок этой самой страницы. Также на странице есть ссылки, и когда нажимаю на эти ссылки, то тот же самый заголовок уже становится видимимым. Думаю, что при переходе на ссылку не срабатывает мой JS. Или может что другое... В общем определенно сам наврятли разберусь.
Если что, код:

```
{
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
}
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
{
     @Override  
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)  
        {  
         mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+                     "document.getElementsByClassName('head')[0].style['display']='none';" +
                 "})()");
        }   
}
```

Comment: Не исправит ли ситуацию mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('head')[0].style['display']='none';" );
?

Comment: Попробуйте `onPageFinished()`

Answer (score 1):

вам нужна loadData вместо loadUrl
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: Можно чуточку поконкретнее про loadData, а то я попробовал и у меня отобразился определенно не страница инета?..

Comment: Везде использовал loadUrl, везде работало.